# ROS service tutorial -- make error

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am just learning ROS. I was following the tutorial here:

[http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29](Service and Client using c++)

Then I tried to 'make' the package, beginner_tutorials, but this is the output I got. There cannot be an error in the already made tutorial packages. Am I missing something?

> [ 75%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.o
> In file included from
> /home/gregkoshmak/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:2:
> /home/gregkoshmak/ros_workspace/beginner_tutorials/srv_gen/cpp/include/beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h:208:
> error: ‘IsMessage’ is not a template
> make[2]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/src/add_two_ints_client.o] Error 1   make[1]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/add_two_ints_client.dir/all]
> Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30052/ros-service-tutorial----make-error/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2012-03-20**:
In the last paragraph, the tutorial offers some hints to fix failing builds. Did you already double-check those?

**Comment by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on 2012-03-20**:
Make sure you've performed the following tutorial, regarding the creation of the srv file, successfully: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_srv. Seems to be a problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From comments: @kshitij
Make sure you've performed the following tutorial, regarding the creation of the srv file, successfully: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv#Creating_a_srv. Seems to be a problem there.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2